# Returning object from json file search

Tags: node.js, json, asynchronous, fs

I'm trying to verify if an incoming request matches a player database, then returning it to a function that will later change the data.

it always returns undefined or false.
I've tried moving the return around and no matter what i do it wont reassign to the output

```
function move(req){
  Verify(req).then((PLAYER)=>{
    console.log(PLAYER);
  })
}

async function Verify(req){
  const PLAYER=false
  fs.readFile('PlayerData.json', 'utf-8', (error , output) => {
      if(error){error}
      else{
        for(let i in JSON.parse(output).PLAYERS.length){
          if(JSON.parse(output).PLAYERS[i].NAME == req.body.PLAYERDATA.NAME){PLAYER=JSON.parse(output).PLAYERS[i];}
        }
      }
  })
  return PLAYER
}
```

Data recived

```
{
  ACTION: 'MOVE',
  DIRECT: 'UP',
  PLAYERDATA: { POS: '11b', NAME: 'dfg', RANGE: '2', POINTS: '1', HEALTH: '3' }
}
```

Playerlist

```
{"PLAYERS":
[{"POS":"5b","NAME":"wer","RANGE":"2", "POINTS":"1", "HEALTH":"3"},
{"POS":"11b","NAME":"dfg","RANGE":"2","POINTS":"1" , "HEALTH":"3"}]}
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fs-promises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html) version of readFile (see how to do that below), or, if you prefer, promisify the readFile method yourself...

```
async function Verify(req){
  const targetName = req.body.PLAYERDATA.NAME;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('PlayerData.json', 'utf-8', (error , output) => {
      if(error) return reject(error);
      
      result = JSON.parse(output);
      for(let player of result.PLAYERS){
        if(player.NAME == targetName) {
          return resolve(player);  // found a name match
        }
      }
      resolve(false);  // did't find the player
    });
  });
}
```

I had to guess a little bit about the OP's JSON result. The OP code says:

```
for(let i in JSON.parse(output).PLAYERS.length) {
```

... which only makes sense if `.length` returns an object, but it sure looks like the OP expects `PLAYERS` to be an array, and length to be that array's integer length. I assumed that to be the case.

**With fs-promises**

If you do choose to use the promise returning variety of `readFile`, then...

```
async function Verify(req){
  const targetName = req.body.PLAYERDATA.NAME;
  const output = await fsPromises.readFile('PlayerData.json', 'utf-8')
  const result = JSON.parse(output);
  for(let player of result.PLAYERS){
    if(player.NAME == targetName) {
      return player;  // found a name match
    }
  }
  return false  // did't find the player
}
```